# Property of a compact subset of an open set in a metric space

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(M, d)$ be a metric space and let $U\subseteq M$ be open. Show that, if $K\subseteq U$ is compact, then there is a $\delta> 0$ so that, for all $x\in K$ and all $y$ not in $U$, we have $d(x, y) \geq \delta$.

I have this question in my analysis class.  I am trying to show that the

$\inf\{d(x, y) : x \in K, y\  \text{not in} \  U\}$

is positive, but I am having trouble understanding why $d(x,y)$ is positive if $K$ is compact. Can anyone help point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $U=M$ then the property is is satisfied by vacuity.

If $U$ is smaller than the whole $M$, for every $x\in K$, take a $\delta_x>0$ small enough so that $B_{\delta}(x)$ is contained in $U$. this is possible since $U$ is open and $x\in U$. This defines an open covering of $K$, $\{B_{\delta_x}(x)\}_{x\in K}$.

Since $K$ is compact, we can extract a finite subcovering $\{B_{\delta_i}(x_i)\}_{i=1}^k$. Assume without loss of generality that  $\delta_1$ is the biggest of all the $\delta_i$. Then the set $V:=\cup_{i=1}^k B_{\delta_1}(x_i)$ covers $K$ and is contained in $U$.

Then $\delta= \delta_1$ satisfies the conditions you wanted since, for every $y\notin U$, ifyou had that  $d(x,y)<\delta$, then $y$ would be an element of $V$ (by the definition of $V$); but $V$ is contained in $U$ so this is impossible. Therefore $d(x,y)\geq \delta$ for all $x\in K$.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is very helpful.

Comment: Your last paragraph is false. Here's a counterexample: let $U=(-2,2)$ and $K=[-1,1]$. I can cover $K$ with $V=(-3/2,3/2)$ which trivially has a finite subcover and you'd pick $\delta = 3/2$. Note that $1+3/2 = 2.5$ leaves plenty of room for choosing $y \in [2,2.5)$ such that $d(1,y)<3/2$ but $y \not\in V$.

Comment: The error is that if $x\in K$ and $y\not \in U$,we can only be sure that $d(x,y)\geq \delta $ when $x\in \{x_i :i=1,...,k\}$ . This can be remedied by taking a finite sub-cover  of $ \{ B_{( \delta_x  / 2) } : x\in K\}$.

Comment: You are right! what a mistake! What am I supposed to do in these cases? Do i delete the answer or edit it? thank you very much for the correction

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to define $d(-,U^c):K\rightarrow \mathbb R$ by $d(x,U^c)=\inf \left \{ d(x,z):z\in U^{c} \right \}$.

$1).\ d(-,U^c)$ is well-defined by glb property of $\mathbb R$.

$2).\ d(x, U^c)>0,\ \forall x\in K$ because if not then there is an $x\in K$ and a sequence $\left \{ z_n \right \}\subseteq U^c$ such that $z_n\rightarrow x$. Now $U^c$ is closed so the foregoing implies that $x\in U^c$, which contradicts the fact that $K\cap U^c=\emptyset$.

$3).\ d(-,U^c)$ is continuous: For any $x,y\in K;\ z\in U^c$, we have

$d(x,z)\geq d(y,z)+d(x,y)$ and $d(y,z)\geq d(x,z)+d(x,y)$ and on taking infs we get

$d(x,U^c)\geq d(y,U^c)+d(x,y)$ and $d(y,U^c)\geq d(x,U^c)+d(x,y)$, from which

$\vert d(x,U^c)-d(y,U^c)\vert \geq d(x,y)$, which shows that $d(-,U^c)$ is continuous.

Siince $K$ is compact, we may now we may conclude that $d(-,U^c)$ has a positive mimimum on $K$. That is, there is a $\delta >0$ such that $d(x,U^c)>\delta ,\ \forall x\in K$.